# How to load local HTML file in Android Browser

Tags: android, html, browser, local

I'm trying to load a local html file in the device browser. I tried using the WebView, but it doesn't work for all devices.

```
//WebView method that didnt work for all devices
WebView w = new WebView(this);
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my.html");
setContentView(w);
```

so i tried this method, which opens the file in an html viewer, but doesn't work because the html i'm trying to load requires javascript

```
// html view that also doesnt work
Intent i = new Intent();
//i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this is optional
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(myFile), "text/*");
startActivity(i);
```

ive looked around for at least a day trying different ways of doing this, like adding

```
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
i.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
```

but they return errors like

```
Unable to start activity android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] typ=text/html }
```

and

```
Unable to start activity android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

the best way for me to do this is to load the html directly from the assets folder, which i know is so simple using a WebView but like i said it doesnt work for devices like the Galaxy Nexus and the Nexus 7, where it does work for devices like the kindle fire and the kindle hd.

but currently the method im using is to save it from the assets folder to external storage and retrieve the file from there to load through an intent, which doesnt work because of javascript issues. any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Did you enable JavaScript on your webView?

Comment: yes, you can see in the post

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried those options?

```
w.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
w.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Comment: just tried those, also tried w.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON) as well as PluginState.ON_DEMAND. didnt work

Comment: @user1459976 do you use ProGruard?

Comment: @user1459976 so no, or you don't know? Does your project has `proguard-project.txt` file or not?

Comment: my project does not have proguard-project.txt file

Comment: @user1459976 does your `project.prorerties` has uncommented line `proguard.config=...`

Comment: oh i didnt even look sorry, i do have proguard-projet.txt file in my project. the line projuard.config=... is commented out.

Comment: well, try running your project with proguard enabled and in proguard-project.txt you have specific line telling about WebView with Javascript interface: `If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface class:` Maybe this might help

Comment: i uncommented the proguard.config=... and added the class name to the -keepclassmembers class fqcn.... portion. doesnt work for nexus 7

Comment: @user1459976 it seems it is a common problem, i came across it many times while googling and there are workarounds. Btw, i hope you added a fully qualified class name of your own JS interface

Comment: the javascript isnt supposed to touch android side. strangely using webview works for kindle fire and kindle fire hd, but not for nexus 7 and galaxy nexus. isnt there a way to open the html in a browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32842/discussion-between-user1459976-and-mocialov-boris)

Comment: @user1459976 I just tried now http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk/DemoTextBoxExpand/src/org/gonevertical/?r=3081#gonevertical%2Ftextboxexpand on my Nexus 4 phone and the result was: HTML became visible for like a second and disappeared, while on emulator 2.1 the page was visible without disappearing. That is weird. GOing to investigate this issue closely tomorrow